# preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset

Tags: php

I want to produce search result all letters that is caps or small,but now it's displaying exact keywords result only,so that i changed my original code `$pattern = "/".$searchTerm."([a-zA-Z0-9])*/";` to like this `$pattern = "/".$searchTerm."([a-zA-Za-ZA-z0-9])*/";`

but this display some errors and output not coming

> **Error :**
>
> Warning: preg_match_all(): Compilation failed: range out of order in
>   character class at offset 14 in /var/app/current/WS/search.php on line
>   30
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /var/app/current/WS/search.php on line 31
>   {"message":"success","response":1,"result":[]}

My search code :

```
if($searchTerm&&$searchType)
    {
        if($searchType=='hash') {
            $query = "SELECT hashTag FROM `".$table."` WHERE hashTag LIKE '%#".$searchTerm."%'";
            $stmt = $database->prepare($query);
            // $stmt->bind_param('s',$searchTerm);
            $stmt->execute();    
            $stmt->store_result();

            if($stmt->num_rows>0) {
                $tempArray = array();
                $stmt->bind_result($hashTag);

                while ($row =$stmt->fetch()) {
                    $pattern = "/".$searchTerm."([a-zA-Za-ZA-z0-9])*/";
                    preg_match_all($pattern,$hashTag,$matches);
                    foreach ($matches[0] as $key => $value) {
                        $finalArray[$value] = "";
                    }
                }

                foreach ($finalArray as $key => $value) {
                    $tempArray = array();
                    $tempArray['hash'] = $key ;
                    array_push($megaArray, $tempArray);
                }       

                $stmt->free_result();
                $stmt->close();
                $finalArray = array();
                $finalArray = $megaArray;

                $message = "success";
                $response = 1;
            } 
        }
```

What is the solution to produce the result to the search term is caps or small?

Comment: The `a-Z` is not in order, because the uppercase `Z` preceds the lowercase `a` in codepoints. And you probably should utilize `preg_quote()` too.

Comment: The original `a-zA-Z` should have gotten upper- and lower-case letters. Why did you think you needed to add `A-z` and `a-Z`?

Comment: yaa my old code is $pattern = "/".$searchTerm."([a-zA-Z0-9])*/"; . but it is only exact result.

see the DB stored like #varun,if i search #VARUN means i want that #varun result,but now i want #varun result means the search term need  
exactly #varun.This is my problem.

Comment: i solved this issue thank you guys for your kind replies,

i changed my codes like this :

if($searchType=='hash')
{
$query = "SELECT hashTag FROM `post` WHERE (hashTag like '%".$searchTerm."%')";
$stmt = $database->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();  
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows>0)
{
$tempArray = array();
$stmt->bind_result($hashTag);
while ($row =$stmt->fetch()) 
{
$tempArray = array();
$tempArray['hashTag']= $hashTag;
array_push($finalArray,$tempArray);
}
$stmt->free_result();
$stmt->close();
$message = "success";
$response = 1;
} 
}

Now it's working fine.once again tq guys